# Graphing Percent Change by Date

Tags: data-visualization, looker-studio

I currently have a line graph that charts store traffic by week. The graph includes a comparison line that showcases store traffic for the given week last year. I would love to add in a line that showcases the percent change we saw this year from last year. Any thoughts on how to do this? See screenshot for visual.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc2Ca.png

Answer (score 0):

Currently you would have to do that in your data source.